# Application of Dynkin's Lemma: Why is this function measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1)$, $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$ be two measurable spaces.

In the lecture note it is written that

for all $A \in \mathcal{A}_1 \times \mathcal{A}_2$ we have

$$\omega_1 \mapsto \int_{\Omega_2} 1_A(\omega_1,\omega_2) K(\omega_1, d \omega_2)$$

is $\mathcal{A}_1$-measurable,

where $K$ is a stochastic kernel from $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1)$ to $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$, i.e.

1. for all $A \in \mathcal{A}_2$ the map $\omega_1 \mapsto K(\omega_1, A)$ is $\mathcal{A}_1$-measurable and
2. for all $\omega_1 \in \Omega_1$ the map $A \mapsto K(\omega_1, A) \in [0,1]$ is a  probability measure on $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$.

Comment: @ user136457 : First remark you might give more detail about which lecture notes you are referring to in your post. Second you can observe the fact that it is easy to show the result for sets $A$ of the form $A_1\times A_2$ where $A_1\in \mathcal{A}_1$ and $A_2\in \mathcal{A}_2$, then my guess is that it might be the result of an application of a "monotone class type theorem" (in the spirit of Fubini's theorem proof) although a simpler (or another) road to the proof might exists. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that

$$\mathcal{D} := \{A \in \mathcal{A}_1 \times \mathcal{A}_2; \omega_1 \mapsto \int_{\Omega_2} 1_{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2) \, K(\omega_1,d\omega_2) \, \text{is measurable}\}$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $A_1 \times A_2 \in \mathcal{D}$ for any $A_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1$, $A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$.

Comment: How do you do this, if the $K(\omega_1,\;\cdot\;)$ are not necessarily *finite* measures?

Comment: @0xbadf00d What do you mean..? The OP was specifically asking about probability measures (hence finite measures).

Comment: Yes, I know. I wanted to know from you if it holds in the mentioned case as well.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see. Why would you expect any trouble if the measures are not finite? As far as I can see, we only need monotone convergence (... and obviously, if the measures are not necessarily finite, then the integral might take the value $+\infty$).

Comment: I see trouble in showing that $\mathcal D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (or at least a $\lambda$-system), since (in contrast to the finite case) it's not possible to conclude $B\setminus A\in\mathcal D$, for $A,B\in\mathcal D$ with $A\subseteq B$, by noting that $1_{B\setminus A}=1_B-1_A$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You are right, there is problem about the closedness under complement... so probably one would need some "uniform" $\sigma$-finiteness for this type of argument.

Comment: A similar result is "proven" [here in Proposition 1.10, page 8](https://ericmoulines.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/mainmc-tome1.pdf). However, it seems like they ignore this problem.

Comment: That would be surprising, wouldn't it? Since the $\lambda$-system argumentation we've talked about before, is exactly the argumentation which is used inside the proof of the monotone class theorem. The problem is that our $\mathcal H$ is *not* a vector space (for the same reason as mentioned before).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Right, that was stupid sorry; obviously we are lacking the vector space property. You could try to define $\mathcal{D}$ as the family of sets for which $$\omega_1 \mapsto \min \left\{n, \int 1_A(\omega_1,\omega_2) \, K(\omega_1,d\omega_2) \right\}$$ is measurable for all $n$. This will avoid the problem "$+\infty-\infty$"... but not sure whether the rest goes through. In any case, you might want to open a new question since it's really a mess to discuss this in comments.

Comment: I already did: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118088/if-kappa-is-a-transition-kernel-and-f-is-measurable-is-int-f-cdot

Comment: I see, if you had mentioned this earlier, this would have saved us some comments. I'll think about it...

Comment: @0xbadf00d In Cinlar's book "Probability and Stochastics" you find a proof of the assertion for $\Sigma$-finite kernels (i.e. kernels which can be written as a countable sum of finite kernels), it's Proposition 6.9. No idea whether there is anything beyond this...

Comment: As long as $f$ does only depend on the second argument, i.e. $f:\Omega_2\to[0,\infty]$, it seems like that the claim even holds in general. It is theorem 6.3 in the book you've mentioned.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, if the function only depends on the second argument it's much easier to prove... but as far as I understood from your question, you are interesting in the more general case that $f$ depends on both variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the collection of sets $A\in\mathcal{A}_{1}\times\mathcal{A}_{2}$
for wich the function is measurable.

For $A=A_{1}\times A_{2}$ with $A_{i}\in\mathcal{A}_{i}$ the function
is $\omega_{1}\mapsto\int_{\Omega_{2}}1_{A}\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},d\omega_{2}\right)=1_{A_{1}}\left(\omega_{1}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},A_{2}\right)$
hence is measurable.

Observe that:

- $\Omega=\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}\in\mathcal{D}$.
- $\int_{\Omega_{2}}1_{A^{c}}\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},d\omega_{2}\right)=K\left(\omega_{1},\Omega_{2}\right)-\int_{\Omega_{2}}1_{A}\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},d\omega_{2}\right)$
  so $\mathcal{D}$ is closed under complementation.
- If sets $A^{\left(i\right)}\in\mathcal{D}$ are disjoint and $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A^{\left(i\right)}$
  then $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\int_{\Omega_{2}}1_{A}\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},d\omega_{2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{\Omega_{2}}1_{A^{\left(i\right)}}\left(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\right)K\left(\omega_{1},d\omega_{2}\right)$
  is measurable.

Proved is now that $\mathcal{D}$ is a Dynkinsystem and this with
$\left\{ A_{i}\times A_{2}\mid A_{1}\in\mathcal{A}_{1},A_{2}\in\mathcal{A}_{2}\right\} \subset\mathcal{D}$.

Collection $\left\{ A_{1}\times A_{2}\mid A_{1}\in\mathcal{A}_{1},A_{2}\in\mathcal{A}_{2}\right\} $
is closed under finite intersection.

Now Dynkins lemma (the Dynkin system generated by π-system is a
σ-algebra.) can be applied and we conclude that

$\mathcal{A}_{1}\times\mathcal{A}_{2}=\sigma\left(\left\{ A_{1}\times A_{2}\mid A_{1}\in\mathcal{A}_{1},A_{2}\in\mathcal{A}_{2}\right\} \right)\subseteq\mathcal{D}$.